# Is Behr primer compatible with Sherwin Williams paint?

Tags: walls, painting

Can I prime walls using Behr primer then paint over the primer using Sherwin Williams paint?

Comment: Close because unclear and too broad, and calls for opinions

Comment: May simply be a poorly written query about using primer and paint from different manufacturers?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I just made a major edit to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

The brand name on the can doesn't really matter, as long as the products are compatible. Read the labels, if your paint says that it cleans up with soap and water you should be able to use it over any type of primer.